# MongoDB - Add property to objects in an array if one does not exist

Tags: mongodb

So I have this collection with a property that is an array. Let's say the property is named buyers. In the beginning, the objects stored in the buyer's array was as the following

```
buyers: [
{
   userId: "1234",
   Prop1: "AAaaa" 
},
{
   userId: "2312",
   Prop1: "Abba" 
},
]
```

After some time we added one property (quantity), to the schema. But the old data still contains just these two properties.

No, I need to query the data and make a sum on that new property 'quantity', with a rule that if that property is missing, it should actually be 1 which is the replacement of the value.

I was trying to use the $ifNull & sum, but it's not adding 1 for each buyer that is missing the quantity property.

this is what I have.

```
$addFields: {
      sumBought: {
        $sum: {
          $ifNull: ["$buyers.quantity", 1],
        },
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could convert the array to a values array using `$map` by adding 1 to mapped array `$ifNull` and then take the `$sum` of mapped array

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      sumBought: {
        $sum: {
          $map: {
            input: "$buyers",
            in: { $ifNull: [ "$$this.quantity", 1 ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hVlD1H4XXCb)

alternatively you can use `$reduce` as well

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      sumBought: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$buyers",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: { $add: [ "$$value", { $ifNull: [ "$$this.quantity", 1 ] } ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pX5J_z7lRSS)

Comment: Woow, Super thanks! Map was what I was missing!!!